# Is async()=>await funcAsync() equivalent to ()=>funcAsync() in C#?

Tags: c#

In the GetOrCreateAsync of learning asp.net core memoryCache, a Func<ICacheEntry, Task> parameter is required, and then I see the sample code as

```
GetOrCreateAsync("allInfo", async e=> await _service.GetAllAsync())
```

I changed it to

```
GetOrCreateAsync("allInfo", e=>_service.GetAllAsync())
```

can also run normally, so I want to know if the two are equivalent, and if they are different, what is the difference?

Comment: Make `_service.GetAllAsync` to throw an exception and see if you spot the difference

Comment: @Fabio,Well, I threw an exception, but there seems to be no difference in the exception information during the debugging phase

Comment: See [eliding async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if the two are equivalent, and if they are different

Yes, They are different.

This one will create a method for `Func<ICacheEntry, Task>`

```
e=>_service.GetAllAsync()
```

but `async ... await` will create a state machine code which means the method could be awaitable automatically.

```
async e=> await _service.GetAllAsync()
```

Here is a sample code, Although this code looks a little stupid but I want to show the different part of code.

```
Action s = ()=>  Task.Delay(100);
```

[code of normal delegate](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4WAUAAgTAjOEAYAEEYFYDc8DMKpIGEkBvccJClXCAFiQFkYAKAShPMs9XwGckBeJK34A+ChABsAOgAiAUwA2AQwCeTGAgQssYTgF9weoA==)

```
Action s = async ()=> await Task.Delay(100);
```

[code of async delegate](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4WAUAAgTAjOEAYAEEYFYDc8DMKpIGEkBvcJclXCAFiQFkAKAShLIvdXwGckBeFABxJmvAHwoAnCgBsAOgAiAUwA2AQwCeDGAgRMsYdgF9whoA==)